# Setting a tooltip using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to set the tooltip of a control that is inside a user control. I cannot modify the user control since it is compiled. The reason for changing the tooltip is because of its language.

```
var wmp_CloseWindowButton = wmp.GetType().GetProperty("CloseWindowButton", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(wmp, null);

var wmp_tooltip = wmp.GetType().GetProperty("ToolTip1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(wmp, null);

var x = wmp_tooltip.GetMethod("SetToolTip");
```

This is where I don't know what to do.

```
x.Invoke ???????
```

The following always returns null.

```
var Mypropertyinfo = wmp_tooltip.GetProperty("ToolTip");
```

Thank you very much in advance
Félix

Comment: Your example that returns null is not using the same name as your code example - "ToolTip" vs "ToolTip1". What kind of app is this? Winforms? WPF? When you run the codem is `x` null?

Comment: Another thought I have is, is the tooltip configured on the button itself or through a ToolTipService object that maintains a reference to the button?

Comment: Winforms. GetMethod("SetToolTip") returns a value, I just don't know what to do with it. Tooltip is the property, Tooltip1 is the name of the control.

Comment: the tooltip is configured on the button itself and x is not null.

Comment: `x.Invoke` would be invoking a method called `SetToolTip` so it would be something like `x.Invoke(wmp_tooltip, thebuttonInstance, "new text")` I think.

Comment: Compilation error.
  mMain.cs(34, 15): [CS7036] No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'parameters' de 'MethodBase.Invoke(object, BindingFlags, Binder, object[], CultureInfo)'

Comment: [Invoke has two parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke) - the object on which to invoke the nethod (in this case the ToolTip object) and an object[] of parameters which are passed to the method itself - which are the control which hosts the tooltip, and the text. So you will need a reference to the button itself - as @TheMuffinMan pointed out - but then you need to pass them as an array - `x.Invoke(wmp_tooltip, new object[] { thebuttonInstance, "new text"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works correctly. I have no idea how to mark your answers.
Thank you

```
var wmp_CloseWindowButton = wmp.GetType().GetProperty("CloseWindowButton", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(wmp, null);
var wmp_tooltip = wmp.GetType().GetProperty("ToolTip1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(wmp, null);
var x = wmp_tooltip.GetType().GetMethod("SetToolTip");
x.Invoke(wmp_tooltip, new object[] {wmp_CloseWindowButton, "new text"});
```

Comment: If this is the solution you used, accept your answer to the question so that everyone knows your question is not open anymore